# Get directory of current php file, which might have changed since the script started to run

Tags: php, linux

I hope you can help. I need to find to way to get the current directory of the currently running PHP script.

The location of the script itself might have changed since the script was started.

I cannot use any magic constants such as `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` as a basis as they appear to be defined by the PHP processor at the beginning of execution and so continue to point to the original location of the script.

To test out ideas, I'm doing the following (from the command line on linux):

1. Have a file named `test.php` in directory `test_1` i.e. `test_1/test.php`
2. Run this file on the command line with: `php test_1/test.php`
3. Open another terminal session and rename the directory with `mv test_1 test_2`
4. Keep an eye on the original terminal and hope you can find that it is reporting the new `test_2` dir not `test_1`

The script used for this test was as follows:

```
<?php
while (true) {
    echo "__FILE__: " . __FILE__ . "\n";
    echo "__DIR__: " . __DIR__ . "\n";
    echo "realpath(__FILE__): " . realpath(__FILE__) . "\n";
    echo "realpath(__DIR__): " . realpath(__DIR__) . "\n";
    echo '-----'. "\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

So, the question: **How do you find out the current directory of the script running now (not where it was when the script started)?**

Comment: Why? though, I'm intrigued.

Comment: Haha, @allen213, it is an issue when we make a deployment and part way through a page load an `include()` loads a file that is newer than those of the first half of the script. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inode of a script will not change, even if it is moved to a different location in the same filesystem.

You could get the inode and pathname of the file at the beginning of the script, using the built-in function [getmyinode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmyinode.php):

```
<?php 
  $myinode = getmyinode();
  $mypath = realpath(__FILE__);
?>
```

Then whenever you want to get the file path, call a function which compares the two and updates the path if necessary:

```
<?php
  function getMyPath() {
    global $myinode, $mypath;
    if (fileinode($mypath) != $myinode) {
      // File moved!
      $searchfrom = '/'; // Maybe you can change this to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
      $mypath = shell_exec("find " . $searchfrom . " -inum " . $myinode . " -print -quit 2>/dev/null");
      if (fileinode($mypath) != $myinode) {
        // error; not found
      }
    }
    return $mypath;
  }
?>
```

It will be very slow to search for the inode if/when the file is moved but I don't see any way around that. Also note that if there are hardlinks then there could be multiple paths to the same file; the `-print -quit` above simply stops after the first one.

This will only work on Linux due to the use of inodes and the `find` shell command.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using the inode, but didn't realise that `find` could use it. The software is for internal use at work and we know the server setup so don't need to worry about Windows or machines without `find`. You are right that it is a bit expensive, but I should be able to get it to make an educated guess to the location of the file and therefore make it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

Maybe this will be helpful?

Comment: Thanks, but as per my original question: "I cannot use any magic constants such as __FILE__ or __DIR__ as a basis as they appear to be defined by the PHP processor at the beginning of execution and so continue to point to the original location of the script." So getting the directory name from the string which will still contain the wrong value doesn't help. `dirname()` does not touch the filesystem, it purely parses the string as a string to attempt to find a directory name in it.